# Do I need "had" in the following examples (past-tense narrative)?

Tags: word-usage, narration

> "It's okay. Minding people's business sometimes means *care*." She
>   flashed me a gleaming grin.
>
> I smiled back. Great, I **had** solved the mystery of Sumire's bruise.
>
> That was what I **had** thought.

This is first-person past tense. Do I need the **had**'s there?

Comment: Why did you think you needed the *hads* there to begin with?

Comment: If you use "had", then it is not past tense, but rather **past perfect tense**. I'm not sure whether you're asking which tense you should use, or whether your examples are past tense. You might want to clarify that.

Comment: I think that the first had should stay, but the second shouldn't. But it's definitely subjective and depends on the meaning you are trying to portray. Check out @Flater's past vs. past perfect tenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*… I had solved the mystery…* is more than fine. *had* is necessary, unless you mean *at that moment,* I solved *the mystery…*, which I suspect you don’t.

*I solved…* without *had* is sometimes used in translation from another language in which it might be perfectly equivalent. It’s almost never used in native English and in that context, it would be rather suspect.

*That was what I had thought* is fine if the meaning is that was what I had thought *in the past…* or *until something changed my mind* and later or subsequently or just now, I stopped thinking that.

*Again? I blurted when I handed Sumire the memory card two weeks later* is relevant exactly how, please? I think all it does is confuse the issue. Further, where did the example come from, that it has to be so verbose, please?